# Android: PreferenceManager vs Context.getSharedPreferences() and why the latter failed me

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

ok, following the Udacity Android Development Course, I reached the part where I'm expected to access the postal code saved to a sharedPreferences file called pref_general.xml, which has the postal code saved in string type and connected to a key called location via key-value pair.

My approach to the problem was to use the getSharedPreferences() method to get the file by name. While that appears to not cause problems because the file didn't turn out null, the attempt to retrieve the postal code resulted in not finding the value via the key and settling on the given default value of the argument.

```
SharedPreferences appPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref_general", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(appPreferences == null) {
            Log.v("ERRORTAG", "Cannot get sharedPreferences file");
        }
        String getPostal = appPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key), "0");
        Log.v("ERRORTAG", getPostal);
```

The 2nd verbose statement on logcat results in the default String value of 0 instead of the value tied to the given key of 94043 postal code.

Now the answer Udacity gave was to use PreferenceManager, which grabs the default lone sharedPreferences file tied to the Activity

```
SharedPreferences appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

The file isn't null AND the retrieved postal code is the given default postal code 94043 set within the sharedPreference file as a key-value pair.

I want to understand why my approach wasn't working; it was quite close. The only difference was how the file was accessed. Please give me an explanation as to why. Thank you.

Comment: Show the code where you created the `pref_general` file and stored the postal code in it.

Comment: On a side note, I hope Udacity isn't teaching you to put string constants in `strings.xml`.  That's for localizable UI strings.

Comment: Udacity is telling us to use deprecated methods to add preferences through SettingsActivity in order to target Gingerbread OS devices. That being said, the string constant for the postal code is in fact created as an xml attribute via android:defaultValue in the pref_general.xml, and the string for it is tied to the strings.xml as apparently something you are against. What do you mean by localizable UI Strings?

Comment: addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general); 
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));

Comment: `strings.xml` is for strings that would be translated into different languages for different locales.  There's some discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428064/where-to-store-string-valuesin-strings-xml-or-in-constants-class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for `PreferenceActivity` say:

> If you are using PreferenceActivity in its old mode, the documentation [for PreferenceFragment] applies to the deprecated APIs here.

And the docs for [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) explain what's happening:

> To retrieve an instance of SharedPreferences that the preference hierarchy in this fragment will use, call getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context) with a context in the same package as this fragment.

This suggests that `PreferenceActivity#addPreferencesFromResource(...)` does not create a `SharedPreferences` file with the same name as the original.  Instead, it merges the file into the default shared preferences.  The `pref_general` file does not exist, and you're basically creating it when you attempt to read from it.  (Though it's not actually created on disk until you edit it.)

Comment: Ah, if it does merge into some default shared preferences file that isn't pref_general.xml, that makes sense.